# How do I prioritise model diagnostics while considering model selection and parameter uncertainty?

Tags: r, glmm, aic, glmmtmb, misspecification

I have fitted a generalized linear mixed model using `glmmTMB` on the data (110 observations, balanced data) collected from an observational study to understand the effect of each predictor (variable) on response (variable):

```r
fit <- glmmTMB(y ~ x1 + x2 + x3 + x4 + (1 | group), family = ..., data = ...)
```

Using DHARMa residuals, I scrutinised `fit`: the DHARMa residuals had uniform distribution and expected dispersion. There was also no pattern when DHARMa residuals were grouped according to `group` and plotted against fitted values.

When DHARMa residuals were plotted against the predictor `x3` and `x4`, [`testQuantiles`](https://rdrr.io/cran/DHARMa/man/testQuantiles.html) showed evidence for deviations from expected locations with p-values of 0.005 and 0.0008, respectively. The residuals had uniform distribution when plotted against the remaining predictors `x1` and `x2`.

I am now stuck because I have been unable to see potential downfalls of some of the following options I have tried:

1. I have added certain transformation of `x4` to see if it improves the model fit (while keeping `x4`). `testQuantiles` now returns p-value of 0.204 of `x3`, but p-value for `x4` is now 0.027. We can refer to this model as `fit.update`.
2. After going through [Brooks *et al*. (2019)](https://esajournals.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/action/downloadSupplement?doi=10.1002%2Fecy.2706&file=ecy2706-sup-0002-AppendixS2.pdf), I also compared a total of 5 models using [`bbmle::AICctab`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/bbmle/index.html) that I was interested in, which were also simpler in complexity *e.g.* `fit.simple.1` had formula `y ~ x1 + x3 + x4 + (1 | group)`. The *best* model (with formula `y ~ x1 + x3 + (1 | group)` had uniform DHARMa residuals and showed no pattern when grouped according to `group`. However, it had non-uniform DHARMa residuals against `x3`.

I am not sure whether I should still consider the best model *the best* because the non-uniform residuals against `x3` gives evidence for model misspecification which might be making the model to have high AICc.

At the same time, there are only a few groups which have high Cook's distance (considering `fit`). I am concerned that these groups might be influencing model estimates drastically as the observations they contribute to data are clearly extreme (way beyond Q3 + 1.5 * IQR) which I can say using some background knowledge.

Given this information:

1. What steps can I follow to quantify the uncertainty in parameter estimates of `fit` (or `fit.update`) given that there is an evidence for model misspecification?
2. What might I miss if I focus on `fit.update` entirely for statistical inference and ignore the best model obtained using `AICc`?

---

Brooks, M. E., Kristensen, K., Darrigo, M. R., Rubim, P., Uriarte, M., Bruna, E., & Bolker, B. M. (2019). Statistical modeling of patterns in annual reproductive rates. Ecology, 100(7), e02706.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only way to get statistical properties that work fully "as advertised" is to completely pre-specify a model.  When a model is "tweaked" to better fit the data, Bayesian uncertainty intervals of frequentist compatibility (confidence) intervals will be too narrow because they don't select model uncertainty.  P-values will be too small.   On the other hand, sticking with an ill-fitting model can be a disaster.  That's why I say in [Regression Modeling Strategies](https://hbiostat.org/rmsc) that using the data to select the model is almost as bad as not doing so.

The best solution to my mind is to pre-specify flexible models that contain parameters for things that matter that you don't know.  Bayesian priors are the only coherent way to handle much of this.  For example you hope a relationship is linear but have a skeptical prior on the amount of nonlinearity as shown [here](https://hbiostat.org/rmsc/genreg#help-in-specifying-priors).

Faraway in his paper [The Cost of Data Analysis](https://www.jstor.org/stable/1390717) showed that the largest impact of model uncertainty comes from how the response variable is transformed.  You are using a very parametric model.  You can solve many problems by using Y-transformation-invariant [semiparametric models](https://fharrell.com/post/rpo).  A detailed case study of using semiparametric ordinal models for continuous Y may be found [here](https://hbiostat.org/rmsc/cony).

Comparing a very limited number of models using AIC or its modifications can be OK, but comparing 5 models results in too low a probability that AIC will select the "right" model.